# Apache Nifi - Write to HDFS in directory structure

Tags: hdfs, apache-nifi

I am looking into nifi to write files to HDFS.
What I would like to is to have the files written in a directory structure based on the File name / year / month / day / hour

So for example a file called "datasetX_xxxx" received on 10 august 2019 at 11 AM would be in directory /datasetX/2019/08/10/11/dataset_xxxx

1) is this possible?
2) how would I set this up?

Thanks in advance.
K

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is certainly possible!

First you need to extract/derive your directory structure from filename then you can put files into HDFS.  Nifi has different processors to accomplish this. While putting files in HDFS, you set processor property  'TRUE' to create desired directory structure in HDFS if not exist. Kindly refer below guides -

[CSV to HDFS](https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/80211/from-csv-to-hive-via-nifi.html)

[Extract directory names from filename](https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/147616/how-to-ingest-files-based-on-the-yyyymmdd-in-their.html)

[Skim through Apache Nifi Processors](https://nifi.apache.org/docs.html)

Answer (score 0):

Configure **`PutHDFS processor`** directory property as below

**`1.Using current timestamp(now) to create directories:`**

```
/datasetX/${now():format('yyyy')}/${now():format('MM')}/${now():format('dd')}/${now():format('HH')}/
```

**`(or)`**

If your flowfile in NiFi have timestamp in its filename (or) as attribute to the flowfile then use [NiFi expression language string functions..etc](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/expression-language-guide.html#strings) to get the value and create directories in HDFS.

Refer to [NiFi expression language](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/expression-language-guide.html#dates), [this](https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/155316/nifi-creating-the-output-directory-from-the-conten.html) and [this](https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/191760/create-dynamic-partitions-based-on-flowfile-conten.html) links for more in built functions that we can use in NiFi.

Comment: @kbruylants, Did the answer helped? If yes accept the answer to close the thread :)  https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work